# Evaluating $\lim _{m\to\infty}\left(\frac1{m^2}+\frac2{m^2}+\frac3{m^2}+\cdots+\frac{m}{m^2}\right)$. Where's my error?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Question is following

$$\lim _{m \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{m^{2}}+\frac{2}{m^{2}}+\frac{3}{m^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{m}{m^{2}}\right)$$

**method-1**
$$\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{m(m+1)}{2 m^{2}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$
**method-2**(applying limits individually)

$$\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{m^{2}}+\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{m^{2}}+\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{m^{2}}+\infty=0$$

Since denominator is always greater than the numerator

What’s wrong with **method-2**. Is it wrong to apply limits individually. If so then how?

Comment: In your second method since $m$ is varying so the number of terms is varying, hence limit of sum = sum of limits is not valid.

Comment: $1=\frac 1 n+ \frac 1 n+..+\frac 1 n$ where there are $n$ terms. What happens if you take the limit for individual terms?

Comment: @pRS mHJN 1 Notice that in your second method each term is not zero rather they are approaching to zero. So you are not adding infinitely many zeroes. Hence the limit is not zero, what you are doing is adding very small numbers together. In fact limit of a sum is equal to sum of limits only if we have finite number of summands

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy   thank u very much. I got your point that limit of sums = sum of limits only when there are finite terms.

Answer (score 3):

First case is correct. Second case wrong: limit of sums equal sum of limits  when we have fixed amount of summands.

Answer (score 1):

The first case works because you have replaced the sum of a varying number of terms with a finite sum of exactly 2 terms, and the replacement is exact with no approximation $$\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2m} \right)$$
This means it is legitimate to interchange the limit and the sum.

The second case is not correct due to there still being a varying number of terms in the sum. It is not legitimate to apply limits term-by-term in such a case. See the comments for a nice counter-example.